# Why do we "extend" condolences?

Tags: word-usage

A relative of mine died and someone used the phrase extend condolences. I know this is a common phrase but it seems very weird. Condolences are something one gives or sends but "extending" something is what you so with your hand.

Why do we say this?

I think it also applies to "extending" gratitude.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I say it because I somehow end up coming off like a jerk when I say that I'm glad someone died.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb to extend has a lot of meanings that one cannot guess from Latin ex and tendere. One of the meanings the verb has acquired is to offer.
So you can extend (offer) credit/protection/money to someone or thanks/a welcome etc. -

I think this use of to extend is a bit stilted. "to offer condolences" would be much clearer. There is a danger to English words. Due to the millions of speakers who use English as second language the use of words can be extended like a chewing gum and finally you don't see what the real center of the word meaning was. Have a look at words like issue or feature - I call them chewing gum words.

Comment: Each time I post here, I am amazed by how complex language is. Its amazing we communicate anything at all!

Comment: @Stan Shunpike - Wow!  Right you are! Language really is an amazing thing.

Comment: But it doesn't, in this context, mean the same thing as *offer*. It refers to sense 8 of *extend* per the OED, which says:  *To hold out, accord, grant (kindness, indulgence) to, towards a person; to offer (advice). †Formerly also, to display (malice), inflict (vengeance), issue (a legal process) against, upon.* So only in the case of extending advice does it really mean *offer*. But we *extend* (hold out, grant etc) many things including *the hand of friendship*.

Comment: @WS2 Google lies then! I typed "define: extends" and that definition didn't come up. Phooey. Ah, well. But what is the difference between holding out and offering? I guess I could hold out my hand but not offer to shake it. It would be weird and confusing but possible.

Comment: @StanShunpike When it comes to the English language, the Oxford English Dictionary does have rather more credibility than Google! The OED is only available on a subscription service so its references will not be found on a Google search - copyright and all that, I suppose.